# Laravel route with optional part of filename

Tags: laravel, routes

With below route I expect to catch `sitemap.xml` and `sitemap-0.xml`. But it only catches `sitemap-0.xml`. Can you help me understand why it doesn't work?

`Route::get('/sitemap{suffix?}.xml', 'SitemapController@sitemap');`

In the controller I then do this: `public function sitemap($suffix = null)`

Of course I can make an additional route called `Route::get('/sitemap.xml', 'FeedsController@sitemap');` but that seems redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you put a constraint on the route via Regular Expression and make that optional. See the following route example should work:

```
<?php

Route::get('/sitemap{suffix?}.xml', 'SitemapController@sitemap')
    ->where('suffix', '-?([0-9]+)?');
```

Why is that?

The Laravel Route works based on the Symfony Route. The optional part in your route is not working because it is the way the Symfony Route works. Therefore, the Symfony Route will not match if there is anything after the optional part because it will then become required.

You have defined the route as below

```
'/sitemap{suffix?}.xml'
```

Note the `.xml` is used after the optional part. So this part `{suffix?}` is now required. It has to have something in the place of `suffix`. And this is why `sitemap.xml` does not work but `sitemap-01.xml` does.

**Explanation for newbies**

The Symfony Route will generate the following regex for `sitemap-09.xml` path:

```
"{^/sitemap(?P<suffix>[^/\.]++)\.xml$}sDu"
```

Now **take** the part that is wrapped with the parenthesis which is called **Named Capturing Group**.

```
(?P<suffix>[^/\.]++)
```

If you want to check the skeleton of the named capturing group that would be as the following:

```
(?P<name>group)
```

Here the **group** part of that regular expression says to match anything **except** a forward slash (/) and a dot (.) before the `.xml`. This means it matches `sitemap-0.xml` or will match anything in place of `-0` in `sitemap-0.xml`.

So when you omit `-0` from `sitemap-0.xml`, the **group** part (as it is NOT optional) does not have anything to match before `.xml`. Thus it does not match `sitemap.xml`.

To solve this issue you should put a constraint on the route as I did above which produces the following regular expression:

```
"{^/sitemap(?P<suffix>-?(?:[0-9]+)?)\.xml$}sDu"
```

Here I tell the route to allow `-` and `[0-9]` **optionally**. Thus it matches both.